# Two papers on the same base of arguments

Tags: mathematics, ethics, paper-submission

I had written a paper (I) on some properties of (real or complex) Hilbert space space valued continuous function to generalize a well-known theorem. I also thought the same about Banach space valued function, but could not do it on that time. After completing the work of paper I, I submitted it to a journal. Later after three weeks, I solved the problem for Banach space valued function in the real case. I wrote this findings in the form of a paper (II), by that time two months were passed from the submission of paper (I). Paper II also conclude the well-known theorem in the real case under a suitable assumption, which I didn't require in Paper I. Also, in paper II, a lemma was needed to handle the complex case, which is not present in Paper I. The main result of two papers uses the same logic with a little modification in the complex case. Both of them were published almost at the same times in two different journals. Is it unethical? If so, What should I do about it now?

Comment: I assume paper 2 properly cites paper 1? Then the reviewers knew what they were doing when they accepted it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see no issues here. More likely developing the first paper gave some insight into the Banach case. This is fairly common, actually, that a proof of one result gives insight into something similar. Proof methods are a powerful, insight driving, thing.

Relax.

Note that someone else, seeing your first paper, might have also said "a Ha" and written the second.

Comment: Thank you @Buffy. I just got nervous.

Comment: At worst one could say "if things had been a little different, it would have been better to have written them together in one paper" (if that's even true). But there's a huge difference between this and "unethical".